# How do we use checkboxes with Parent Child relation in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, checkbox, jstl

I got into following situation where we have checkboxes after each entities

```
Supervision c
  Internal  c
  External  c

Finance    c
  Car      c 
  House    c 
  Mutual Funds  c
```

In Spring MVC, i have created a class which holds following:

```
   private boolean supervision;
   private boolean finance;
   private List<Finances> finances; //enum
   private List<Supervision> supervisions; //enum
```

At UI i have done following

```
   <form:checkbox path="obj.finance" /> //Parent
   <c:foreach  FinancesEnum>
      <form:checkbox path="obj.finances"  />    //Child
   </c:foreach>
```

Is this correct way of handling checkboxes with parent child relationship or not? Are there more available things in spring mvc to handle this? I had some search but jumps into stackoverflow links where unable to find related case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the "correct" way. And no there are no spring mvc out of the box ways available.